# Swing and Java EE integration

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

I have a working java swing application that I need to convert into a server client setup. I have done a lot of research in how I can do this and my option of choice is Java EE of which i know nothing little of. My swing GUI was done with netbeans thus the GUI uses netbeans generated code.

How best can refactor my application to easily convert it into a server client setup?

During my initial developed i tried to implement a lot of Object Orientation Design. Because of the usage of netbeans restructuring the design of the application has turned out to be a nightmare as i have to rewrite most my code during refactoring. I have separate functionality as in which part will form the server and which will form the client.

How can i achieve this with Java EE

Comment: Two (seemingly quite different) questions & a request for recommendations of offsite resources.  How to vote to close? So many possibilities, so little time..

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org) (Google Web Toolkit). It is a Java framework that separates server and client sides. Client code is entirely written in Java and automatically transformed in JavaScript.

The client side uses *widgets* that look like a lot to Swing components (Panels with layouts, Grids, etc.).
I invite you to take a look at their [showcase](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html).

GWT can also be integrated with following injection frameworks:

- Guice (server side)
- GIN (client side)

Hope it helps.